# Weird behaviour of CI after a redirect()

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a strange bug during the password recovery process.
When a user loses his pwd, the app send an email with a token inside the recovery link ( http://localhost/reset-password/f38fd00aa975b28c70f54d948d20de40 for exemple ) This token is an unique key inside the user table.

In the routes.php, i have :

```
$route['reset-password/(:any)'] = "/user/reset_password_form/$1";// new password form
$route['reset-password'] = "/register/reset_password"; //simple email form
```

then, reset_password_form generates a form with the token as hidden input :

```
public function reset_password_form($hash = NULL) {  //create form to change password, with user validation hash inside 
    $user_id = $this->user_model->get_id_by_confirmation_code(strip_tags($hash));
    if (isset($user_id)) {

        $this->data['validation_code'] = $hash;
        $this->data['title'] = $this->lang->line('user_title_password_edit', FALSE);
        $this->template->load('default', 'register/reset_password_form', $this->data);
    }

    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error',  $this->lang->line('user_error_reset_password', FALSE));
        redirect('reset-password');
    }
```

the view:

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => '');
echo form_open('user/edit_password', $attributes) ?> 
<input type="hidden" id="validate" name="validate" value="<?=$validation_code?>">        
<div class="form-group">
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Password confirmation" class="form-control">
</div>
<button type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change password</button>
</form>
```

Finally, the user/edit_password function changes the user password with a new one.

```
public function edit_password() {    //get new password and change it

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_confirm', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('validate', 'Validate', 'trim|alpha_numeric|required');   
    if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {  

        //STRANGE BUG
        $URL = '/reset-password/'.$this->input->post('validate');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
        redirect($URL); 
    } 
    else {
        //change pssword
    }   
}
```

The bug happen when the form validation fail : i'm suposed to be redirected to the previous form ( /reset-password/hash) with a flashdata error message, but **the error message dont display.**

Much more weird : even if i'm on the right form ( but without error message) if i decides to click on another menu item (for exemple /home) , **it immediately displays the /reset-password form** ( /register/reset_password in the routes) **with the error message i was supposed to get previously.**

As if the full php instruction was kept in stamp and launched after whatever action.

PS : as edit_password() and reset_password_form() are in the same controller, i could have used $this->reset_password_form($hash) instead of redirect() but it has exactly the same effect !

ps2: here is the register/reset_password:

```
public function reset_password() {

    //display forgotten password form page
    $this->data['title'] = 'Forgotten password';
    $this->template->load('default', 'register/reset_password', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Would ask you to use the second parameter of the `redirect (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect)`. For example: `redirect($URL, 'refresh');`

Comment: Show `/register/reset_password` code.

Comment: Nil'z - adding the 'refresh' paramater dont change anything.

Comment: Tpojka, i added this function

Comment: In block `if ($this->form_validation->run() === false) {` you should load view, not redirect. Check [basic docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller) about it.

Comment: Why ? i redirect users after many form validations in the app, thats the only redirection i get stuck with

Answer (score 0):

you recovery link  http://localhost/reset-password/f38fd00aa975b28c70f54d948d20de40 is not finding controller. CI is looking for your token number as controller